# Linearity of the Conjugate operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

The output of `Grad[Conjugate[x + y + z], {x, y, z}]` is

```
{ Derivative[1][Conjugate][x + y + z], 
  Derivative[1][Conjugate][x + y + z], 
  Derivative[1][Conjugate][x + y + z]}
```

Is there a way to change the behavior to `Conjugate[Grad[x+y+z,{x,y,z}]]`?

Some context for the question: this sort of operation is part of manipulations of solutions to PDEs using complex arithmetic, with the understanding that the coordinates are all real-valued.  In general, I have no way to know in advance the exact form of the expression that I need to process.

Comment: Perhaps you could apply `ComplexExpand` to the result?

Comment: This might be garbage-in, garbage-out. It amounts to "d/dz" applied to "z-bar"., which would be zero. Except it seems some other result is wanted here? Might be good to give a nontrivial concrete example of input and desired output, that is, an example where some complex values are present.